# chart.js filltext object moved when tooltip is generated because of legend not displaying

Tags: plugins, tooltip, chart.js, ng2-charts

I wonder if anyone ran into similar situation like this.
I am using Chart.js to create a bar chart. One of the requirements for the bar chart component is to display bar data value on the bar itself. I created a simple plugin to do so and it works fine until I notice a display bug.

When hovering over any bars and the tooltip displays, the bar data value got pushed down a bit. I am not sure what happened. It seems that somehow the tooltip adds some sort of space in the chart.

Does anyone ever experience similar behavior?

[image]

[image]

Below is the plugin created to add the bar data value:

```
  Chart.pluginService.register({
afterDraw : function (chart ,easingValue, options) {
  var configOptions = chart.config.options;
  if (configOptions.barValueDisplay){
    var ctx = chart.chart.ctx;
    var scales = chart.scales;
    var datasets = chart.config.data.datasets;

    for(var i = 0; i< datasets.length; i++){
      var meta = chart.getDatasetMeta(i);
      var elements = meta.data
      var yScale = scales['y-axis-0'];
      for (var j = 0; j < elements.length; j++) {
        var view = elements[j]._view;

        var text = configOptions.barGoals ? datasets[i].rawData[j] :datasets[i].data[j];
        var textWidth = ctx.measureText(text).width
        var x = view.x - textWidth / 2;
        var y = yScale.bottom-15;
        ctx.save();
        ctx.fillStyle = configOptions.barValueDisplay.color;
        ctx.fillText(text, x, y);
        ctx.restore();
      }
    }
  }
}});
```

**UPDATE**:
After creating a JSFiddler example, I realize that this behavior is related to legend not displaying.

So, any ideas how this could be addressed without displaying legend? Thanks

https://jsfiddle.net/charleschiu/9fc8n7cb/29/

Comment: I found the cause but haven't figured out a solution yet. When legend is disabled, tooltip display is pushing down the value. As of why, I have no idea yet. I am trying to figure out how to prevent this. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: I noticed the legend connection also, but have yet been able to figure out how to stop the text from moving. What I so far observed: With the legend, `canvas height = chart + legend`. Without the legend, `canvas height = chart`. When the numbers initially render, it is using just the chart height to figure out `yScale.bottom`. When the tooltip hover is triggered, however, it seems like it is updating the whole chart using the chart + legend height. I created a shortened version of your JSFiddle that makes the problem clearer: https://jsfiddle.net/9fc8n7cb/31/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was facing the same issue and posted an issue on the repository. Here's the reply:

> The reason this is happening is that the tooltip is drawing text using
>   a different textBaseline. The plugin in your fiddle doesn't set it so
>   it will be whatever it last was.
>
> I would change your plugin to have the following
>
> ```
> var text = 'test';
> var x = view.x;
> var y = yScale.bottom;
> ctx.textBaseline = 'top';
> ctx.textAlign = 'center';
> ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 0, 255, 1)';
> ctx.fillText(text, x, y);
> ```

I tried it on the Fiddle and it works now!

Comment: Yes! that solves the issue!! Any idea what a textBaseline is in this case? Chart.js is still a mystery to me. :P

Comment: It solved mine too :) textBaseline isn't a Chart.js property, but rather a general HTML canvas property. It specifies the reference baseline which the text is positioned to. The default value is "alphabetic", which meant that when new fillText was created by the tooltip, the position of the original text was re-positioned in reference to the tooltip text as well. For more info read [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/textBaseline).

Comment: ah..yeah...sorry..it takes sometime to get to this. still learning how stackoverflow eco system works. :)